# How to a make new tkinter button for every passswordname in my database

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

> Hi i am trying to create a password manager with the intention of helping myself learn python and tkinter and sqlite3 however i have ran into a problem,everytime i create a new password i want a button  to appear showing that passwordname and then the user could click on it to access their actual password.I have attempted to do this via a for loop however while it loops through every password in my database it does not generate my button.Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance here is my code(the for loop is between lines 89 and 92).

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *     
from tkinter import messagebox


#creating database
conn=sqlite3.connect("Passwords.db")
cursor=conn.cursor()
#creating table-num of quotation is number of lines,name of field then datatype e.g passwordNameoutofdatabase text
cursor.execute("""create table IF NOT EXISTS Passwords
(passwordName text PRIMARY KEY
,UserName text
,password text
)""")#inside are columns/categorys
#login window
login=Tk()
login.title("Password Manager")
login.geometry("1366x768")
screen_width=login.winfo_screenwidth()#gets screen width
screen_height=login.winfo_screenheight()#gets screen height

loginBox=Entry(login,width=100)
loginBox.pack()


def loginClick():


    if loginBox.get()=="steve":
        
        #main window
     
        # creating main password screen window
        main = Toplevel()
        main.title("Password Manager")
        main.geometry("1366x768")
        screen_width = main.winfo_screenwidth()  # gets screen width
        screen_height = main.winfo_screenheight()  # gets screen height

        # setting background
        canvas = Canvas(main, width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        canvas.config(bg="white")
        canvas.pack()
        # creating lines
        canvas.create_line(200, 0, 200, screen_height, fill="blue", width=25)
        canvas.create_line(0, 100, screen_width, 100, fill="blue",
                           width=25)  # x,y,x1,y1 warning grid system is weird lower y is higher
        # creating labels
        passwordLabel = Label(main, bg="white", text="Passwords",
                              font=("freesans", 20))  # set window then text then font then size
        passwordLabel.place(x=50, y=50)
        
     
        # commands for buttons
        def newPasswordclick():
            # creating Labels for search bars and title
            newPasswordlabel = Label(main, text="Create Password Screen", bg="white", font=("freesans", 20))
            newPasswordlabel.place(x=215, y=50)

            def nameEntry():
                passwordNameoutofdatabase = NameofPassword.get()
                username = Name.get()
                password = Password.get()  # gets input from the input box
                cursor.execute("""SELECT passwordName
                                FROM Passwords
                                WHERE passwordName=?
                                """,
                (passwordNameoutofdatabase,))#selects passwordName1 from table then Selects Where column = passwordNameoutofdatabase/any variable as variables by question marks in sqlite3
                primaryKeyCheck=cursor.fetchone()
                print(primaryKeyCheck)
                #Insert passwordNameoutofdatabase,Username,password
                if primaryKeyCheck!=None:
                    NameofPassword.delete(0, END)  # deletes text within the range of 0 to end
                    Name.delete(0, END)
                    Password.delete(0, END)
                    messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR",message="Already have a password with this name")
                else:
                    NameofPassword.delete(0, END)  # deletes text within the range of 0 to end
                    Name.delete(0, END)
                    Password.delete(0, END)
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Passwords (passwordName,Username,password )VALUES(?,?,?)",(passwordNameoutofdatabase,username,password,))#Inserts variables into table by referencing which variables correspond to each column
                    conn.commit()
                    cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM Passwords")#Selects Passwords table
                    Data=cursor.fetchall()#fetches everything selected
                    cursor.execute("SELECT passwordName FROM Passwords")#selects password name from table
                    passwordNames=cursor.execute("Select passwordName FROM Passwords")
                    Passwords=cursor.execute("SELECT* FROM Passwords")
                    for passwordNames in Passwords:
                            Button(main,text=(str(passwordNames)),font=("freesans",20))
                            print("steve")

                    cursor.close()#closes database
                    print(Data)#prints everything fetched

                if passwordNameoutofdatabase != "" and username != "" and password != "":  # checks that the user has typed in all the input boxes
                    NameofPassword.destroy()  # destroy destroys labels and other widgets
                    Name.destroy()
                    Password.destroy()
                    UserNameLabel.destroy()
                    nameEnter.destroy()
                    newPasswordlabel.destroy()
                    NameofPasswordlabel.destroy()
                    PasswordLabel.destroy()

            # labels for buttons
            NameofPasswordlabel = Label(main, text="Enter the name of your password", bg="white", font=("freesans", 10))
            NameofPasswordlabel.place(x=215, y=125)

            UserNameLabel = Label(main, text="Enter your username or email address", bg="white", font=("freesans", 10))
            UserNameLabel.place(x=215, y=175)

            PasswordLabel = Label(main, text="Enter your password", bg="white", font=("freesans", 10))
            PasswordLabel.place(x=215, y=225)
            # creating search bars
            NameofPassword = Entry(main, width=100, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="black",
                                   highlightcolor="black")
            NameofPassword.place(x=215, y=150)

            Name = Entry(main, width=100, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="black",
                         highlightcolor="black")  # highlight attributes create border
            Name.place(x=215, y=200)

            Password = Entry(main, width=100, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
            Password.place(x=215, y=250)



            # buttons
            nameEnter = Button(main, text="Enter", command=nameEntry)
            nameEnter.place(x=850, y=250)

        # creating buttons
        NewPasswordImg = PhotoImage(file="C:\VsCode\Password Manager\Create Password Button.png")
        newPassword = Button(main, image=NewPasswordImg, compound="center", text="Create new password",command=newPasswordclick)  # to combine text with image need to set compound to center,left or right which determines where text is put
        newPassword.config(height=50, width=150)
        newPassword.place(x=20, y=125)
        
        main.mainloop()

loginButton=Button(login,text="Login",font=("freesans",20),command=loginClick,width=5,height=10)
loginButton.pack()

login.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to improve your skills on Python, I recommend you to use  classes, which are very useful when manipulating UI like windows on tkinter.

As for your problem with buttons not being generated, you could try putting them in a list.

I tried to do something with passwords and usernames, appearing on a window with some buttons. The approach is different, but it may give you some ideas for your project.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk

CONNECT_APP_DIMENSIONS=("400", "200")
PASSWORD_APP_DIMENSIONS=("800", "500")


USERNAME_PASSWORD_IN_DB=[
    ['banane_user', 'banane_password'],
    ['kiwi_user', 'kiwi_password'],
    ['patate_user', 'patate_password'],
]

class PasswordApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry(PASSWORD_APP_DIMENSIONS[0]+"x"+PASSWORD_APP_DIMENSIONS[1])

        # ---- ADDING GESTION ----

        # username entry
        self.username_entry=tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        self.username_entry.focus_set()
        self.username_entry.insert(tk.END, "new_username")
        self.username_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
        # password entry
        self.password_entry=tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        self.password_entry.focus_set()
        self.password_entry.insert(tk.END, "new_password")
        self.password_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
        # add username/password button
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self, text="add", command=self.add_account)
        self.add_button.grid(row=0,column=2)
        # status label
        self.status_text=tk.StringVar(self)
        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.status_text)
        self.status.grid(row=0,column=3)

        # ---- END ADDING GESTION ----

        # intiliaze some list
        self.display_buttons=[]
        self.password_status_texts=[]
        self.password_labels=[]

        # make a copy of DB
        self.database = USERNAME_PASSWORD_IN_DB.copy()

        # display username/password list
        self.refresh_list()

    def refresh_list(self):
        cpt_row = 1
        simple_cpt = 0

        for username_password in self.database:
            # new password was added
            if simple_cpt < len(self.display_buttons):
                cpt_row += 1
                simple_cpt += 1
                continue
            # display password button
            self.display_buttons.append(
                tk.Button(
                    self,
                    text=username_password[0], 
                    command= lambda simple_cpt=simple_cpt: self.display_password(db_id=simple_cpt)
                )
            )
            self.display_buttons[simple_cpt].grid(row=cpt_row,column=0)
            # status label
            self.password_status_texts.append(tk.StringVar(self, '******'))
            self.password_labels.append(tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.password_status_texts[simple_cpt]))
            self.password_labels[simple_cpt].grid(row=cpt_row,column=1)

            cpt_row += 1
            simple_cpt += 1

    def display_password(self, db_id):
        # updating label associated to username
        self.password_status_texts[db_id].set(self.database[db_id][1])

    def add_account(self):
        # getting user inputs
        username=self.username_entry.get()
        password=self.password_entry.get()
        # check minimum size
        if len(username) < 4 or len(password) < 4:
            self.status_text.set("Incorrect username/password")
            return
        # check username not already in self.database
        for username_password in self.database:
            if username_password[0] == username:
                self.status_text.set("Username already in DB")
                return
        # adding username/password to DB
        self.database.append([username, password])
        # refreshing list
        self.refresh_list()

class ConnectionApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry(CONNECT_APP_DIMENSIONS[0]+"x"+CONNECT_APP_DIMENSIONS[1])

        # username entry
        self.entry=tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.insert(tk.END, "username")
        self.entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

        # connect button
        self.connect_button = tk.Button(text="connect", command=self.connect)
        self.connect_button.grid(row=0,column=1)

        # status label
        self.status_text=tk.StringVar()
        self.status = tk.Label(textvariable=self.status_text)
        self.status.grid(row=0,column=2)

    def connect(self):
        if self.entry.get() == "steve":
            self.status_text.set("Connected")
            self.password_app=PasswordApp()
            self.destroy()
        else:
            self.status_text.set("Unknown user")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect_app=ConnectionApp()
    connect_app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the button widget in Tkinter, you need to make sure you use methods such as place(), grid(), pack(). I have seen that you have used these methods throughout your code, but you need to make sure you add a display method after you create the button. An example of this is below. But remember you cannot use pack() method when using grid() or place() methods, so you might need to alter your code.

```
    for passwordNames in Passwords:
        Button(main,text=(str(passwordNames)),font=("freesans",20)).pack()
```